# How to map array items to inner array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that needs to be redone (preferably a built-in function of PHP):

```
[
   0 => ['ax' => 'Aland Islands'],
   1 => ['as' => 'American Samoa'],
   2 => ['am' => 'Armenia']
];
```

Need to remake on:

```
[
    'ax' => 'Aland Islands'
    'as' => 'American Samoa'
    'am' => 'Armenia'
];
```

Comment: What did you try ? Where are you stuck at ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: `print_r(array_merge(...$a));`

Answer (score 0):

You can select inner array and use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to create new array with target structure.

```
$arr = [
    0 => ['ax' => 'Aland Islands'],
    1 => ['as' => 'American Samoa'],
    2 => ['am' => 'Armenia']
];
```

```php
$newArr = array_merge($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]);
```

If the array contain many inner array, use

```
$newArr = array_merge(...$arr);
```

Also you can iterate array and insert inner array into new variable.

```
foreach ($arr as $item){
    $key = array_keys($item)[0];
    @$newArr[$key] = $item[$key];
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/13A9I)

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$array = [
    0 => ['ax' => 'Aland Islands'],
    1 => ['as' => 'American Samoa'],
    2 => ['am' => 'Armenia']
 ];

print_r(
    array_reduce($array, 
                    function ($c, $i) {
                        return array_merge($c, $i);
                    },
                    []
                )
       );
```

Outputs:

> Array
>   (
>    [ax] => Aland Islands
>    [as] => American Samoa
>    [am] => Armenia
>   )

A very useful function, goes well beyond of sum/product accumulation !